# Is a break-of-study a hindrance to getting a PhD?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I live in a developing country. I want to go to USA for higher studies and plan to acquire a PhD there. But since I do not have enough money to go there, I need to have a job first to collect my money. May be the job is not relevant to my academic field of interest.

Are these types of break-of-studies hindrances to getting PhDs?

Answer (score 6):

A "break-of-study" is not a hindrance *per se*. It has side effects (you get older, acquire a family, and so on), and some of these can make it a little trickier to get a Ph.D. In particular, you might find the answers to this question: [Can one excel in graduate school with a demanding family life?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9769/can-one-excel-in-graduate-post-graduate-school-with-a-demanding-family-life/9787#9787) very relevant in terms of the challenges of doing a Ph.D with a family.

But again, a break-of-study in and of itself is not a bad thing. Now if the job you are looking for takes you far away from your intended field of research, then you might have to explain your background on your application and somehow establish that you have a continuing interest and basic knowledge in the field (which may have changed since you graduated). You can do this by taking courses online, or by doing research projects on the side, and so on.